# how do I add API code to Discord.py command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

so i have this idea to make a weather command from a friend and i started working on it today. installed the packages, got the code set up, ect. so i have this code below for my weather API code and i want to get it into a command. (!weather). someone in the DPY guild recommended aiohttp and that looks too difficult because i am a newer programmer. is there any solution to this that someone can spoonfeed me? API code is below:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}


def weather(city):
    city = city.replace(" ", "+")
    res = requests.get(
        f'https://www.google.com/search?q={city}&oq={city}&aqs=chrome.0.35i39l2j0l4j46j69i60.6128j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8', headers=headers)
    print("Searching...\n")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    location = soup.select('#wob_loc')[0].getText().strip()
    time = soup.select('#wob_dts')[0].getText().strip()
    info = soup.select('#wob_dc')[0].getText().strip()
    weather = soup.select('#wob_tm')[0].getText().strip()
    print(location)
    print(time)
    print(info)
    print(weather+"°C")


city = input("Enter the Name of City -> ")
city = city+" weather"
weather(city)
print("Have a Nice Day:)")

# This code is contributed by adityatri
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a API key from the weathermap website.
This is an example of what this could look like. Its easily translatable into a command.

In case you want to make it its own function, you can just use this code.
What will be returned is a tuple.

```
list_weather = weatherFrog()
print(list_weather[0])
```

0 would be the temperature, 1 the humidity and 2 the description.

Code:

```
def weatherFrog(city):
    api_key = YOUR_API_KEY
    base_url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        y = x["main"]
        current_temperature = y["temp"]
        current_humidiy = str(y["humidity"]) + "%"
        z = x["weather"]
        current_temperaturetwo = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15, 2)) + " Degrees Celsius"
        en_weather_description = z[0]["description"]

        return current_temperaturetwo, current_humidiy, en_weather_description
```

Comment: can you show me how this would look in a DPY command?